# Mathematics - Distribute a list of numbers over an interval

Tags: excel, function, math

My problem is simple.
I am searching a mathematical function to distribute number over an interval.

For example I have this list :

```
[2; 4; 9; 14]
```

And in my case I wish

```
2  -> 1  = f(2)
14 -> 20 = f(14)
4  -> f(4) = ?
9  -> f(9) = ?
```

This is just an example I am searching for f(x).

Someone would have any idea ?

Thanks for advance ! :)

Comment: Can you explain more about what you want this function to do? What is the interval you want to distribute numbers over? How do you want them distributed? A trivial function of `f(x)=x` will distribute the inputs over the same interval as you allow for valid inputs but is probably not what you have in mind. Similarly `f(x) = x%20` will distribute all your numbers over the range 0 to 19 but again I have no idea if this is actually what you want...

Comment: It occurs to me that you might be just wanting to scale your numbers to a given range so you want a linear function. http://www.coolmath.com/algebra/08-lines/12-finding-equation-two-points-01 shows you the equation for a line through two points. if you know two points on a line (here your f(2) and f(14)) then you can get the formula for a line through those two points and then use that to work out the rest of your values. If this is indeed what you want...

Comment: I searched a linear function sorry. Nico Schertler's answer helped me :)

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a linear function, then:

```
f(x) = lowerFunc + (x - lowerX) * (upperFunc - lowerFunc) /  (upperX - lowerX),
```

where:

```
lowerFunc: function value at the lower end
upperFunc: function value at the upper end
lowerX: x parameter at the lower end
upperX: x parameter at the upper end.
```

For your example:

```
f(x) = 1 + (x - 2) * (20 - 1) / (14 - 2)
     = 1 + (x - 2) * 19/12
f(2) = 1
f(4) = 4.1666
f(9) = 12.08333
f(14) = 20
```

Comment: Thank you very much that was what I was looking for ! :)
I forgot to precise that I searched a linear function :)